# Income Tax Deduction / Reimbursement of Rs.15000/- per year

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction, medical-bill

Can the purchase of medical equipment like Blood Monitor Machine, Blood Sugar Machine etc. be claimed under the medical reimbursement or income tax deduction of up to Rs.15000 per financial year for individuals in India?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag.

Answer (score 1):

Medical Reimbursement benefit of Rs 15,000 is only allowed if claimed via employer. i.e. you cannot claim this directly while filing tax returns.

Medicines, diagnostic tests, small equipment, hospital treatment etc are all covered.

However this needs to be taken up with the policy of employer; he may have more stringent rules, i.e. he may ask for a prescription from doctor that such an equipment is required.

Answer (score 1):

From April 2018, Medical reimbursement tax benefit is gone.

However, there is Section 80D (Preventive health checkup) which allows 5000 Rs for the cost incurred for preventive health check-ups for self, spouse, children or parents. So I guess you are covered.